# Heroku logging to open source log tool

Tags: heroku, logging

Are there any open source logging tools that supports Heroku log drains? I want to be able to store my logs on disk or S3 then query the logs. I don't need a lot of features. I found that the PaaS logging solutions are way too expensive for my volume (150gb/month).